# Delphi: Can I extend TDateTimePicker to support another calendar system? How?

Tags: delphi, datepicker, calendar, persian

I want to implement a calendar system (like Gregorian calendar) as a TDateTimePicker.

1) I want to know can I extend TDateTimePicker class to use its visual features but changing its calendar calculation system to match my calendar system?

2) If so then what I must to do? Which of the classes inside must be altered or extended to change its calculation system? what is the starting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TDateTimePicker` is just a thin wrapper around Microsoft's [DTP control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761727.aspx). It does not support changing the underlying calendar system.

[About Date and Time Picker Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761726.aspx)

> **The control is based on the Gregorian calendar**, which was introduced in 1753. It will not calculate dates that are consistent with the Julian calendar.

Comment: FYI: The Gregorian calendar, which was introduced in the same year in all  countries

Answer (score 2):

here is persian date picker :

https://github.com/A1Gard/PDate

### [image]

about this:

```
The best Delphi & lazarus unit for convert windows standard DateTime to PersianDate & TimeStamp
version 1.3.1:

some bug fixed
version 1.3:

added lazarus compatibility
added function GetTheFirstDayOfThisMonth
added function GetTheFirstDayOfThisWeek
added function GetPersianDayWeek
added function Delphi DatePicker component
fixed bug in PersiantoGer function
version 1.2:

added function DateTimeToUnix
added function UnixToDateTime
version 1.1:

added function UIntToDateTime
added function GerToWord
added function PersianToInt
version 1:

added function GerToPersian
added function PersiantoGer
```

[Author persian descrption](http://4xmen.ir/datepicker-%D9%88-%D8%AA%D9%82%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%85-%DB%8C%D9%88%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AE-%D9%87%D8%AC%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D9%84%D9%81%DB%8C-%D9%88/)